# Counterexample to: $f$ is Riemann Integrable if and only if its discontinuous set is Jordan measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The forward direction is covered in some textbooks. But the reverse I am only able to find sparingly. Is this a counterexample?:

$f=\begin{cases}
0 & (x\not\in\mathbb{Q})\\
1/n & (x\in\mathbb{Q})
\end{cases}$

where if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ we write $x=m/n$ such that $n\not| m$. This is the pathological "continuous at irrational points but discontinuous at rational points" which integrates to $0$.

Edit: "some textbooks", maybe not "most"

Comment: *Which* textbooks? The theorem that I am aware of is that a bounded function $f\colon[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if the *Lebesgue* measure of the set of its points of discontinuity is $0$. This is known as the *Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability*.

Comment: I believe Munkres covers it.

Comment: See my answer to [Jordan measure zero discontinuities a necessary condition for integrability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130).