# Three Notions of Small

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, math-history, descriptive-set-theory

I’m currently learning about the history of the development of the Lebesgue integral in Thomas Hawkins’s book “Lebesgue’s Theory of Integration; It’s Origins and Development”

Hawkins is stressing how much early confusion about the Riemann integral came from conflating three different notions of “small” subsets of reals: two topological notions and one measure theoretic notion. The three notions are:

1. **Nowhere dense**: A set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is *nowhere dense* if and only if $\text{int}(\text{cl}(X)) = \emptyset$.
2. **First species:** For $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $X’$ denote the set of limit points of $X$. Let $X^{(n)} = ( \cdots ((X’)’)’ \cdots )’$, where limit points are taken $n$ times. $X$ is *first species* if and only if $X^{(n)} = \emptyset$ for some $n$.
3. **Zero Jordan Outer Content:** Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and let $\mathcal{I} = \{I_1, \cdots, I_n\}$ be a finite collection of intervals such that $X \subseteq \bigcup_j I_j$. The Jordan outer content of $X$ is $c_o(X) = \inf_{\mathcal{I}} \sum_{I \in \mathcal{I}} \ell(I)$, where $\ell(I)$ is the length of the interval $I$. A set has *zero Jordan outer content* if and only if $c_o(X) = 0$.

Hawkins’s book gives the following results:

- Dini proved that every first species set has zero Jordan outer content.
- Volterra prove that there are nowhere dense sets with positive Jordan outer content.
- du Bois Reymond independently proved that there are nowhere dense sets that aren’t of first species (this is implied by Volterra + Dini, of course).

This leaves open two possible containments.
(A) Is every first species set nowhere dense?
(B) Is every set of zero Jordan content nowhere dense?
I think both of these should be true, but I’d like to have my understanding checked. Thanks!

Comment: To state some standard results, first species implies Jordon content zero implies nowhere dense, with no implication reversible. More precisely, nowhere dense means it's closure is not dense in any interval, whereas [scattered](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/oMfQxIVsQEo/m/F-DGhg4Rtg8J) (a larger notion of smallness than first species) has the property that it's closure is not dense in any perfect set, including very small Cantor sets having Lebesgue measure zero or even Hausdorff dimension zero. **(continued)**

Comment: A Jordan content zero set is such that it's closure also has Jordan content zero, and hence its closure cannot contain a non-degenerate interval, and hence Jordan content zero implies nowhere dense & Lebesgue measure zero (indeed, even the closure of a Jordan content zero set is nowhere dense & Lebesgue measure zero). [This Mathematics SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/870108/13130) may be of interest regarding Jordan measure zero sets and Riemann integrability, and [this History of Science and Mathematics SE answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/8186/264) for some history.

Comment: Thanks for these additional comments, Dave!

Comment: There is also a beautiful book by Oxtoby, named Measure and Category, that treats questions linked to the one you ask. But I don't really know if there is a non-empty intersection!

Comment: Joe, your comment (flagging me) led me back here, where I see that I wrote "it's" instead of the correct "its" THREE (3) TIMES! Once is an oversight, twice not so much, but three times -- especially when the third is in a continuation of the comment -- is really bad . . . If anything, one probably suspects the fourth instance where I correctly wrote "its" was a mistakenly made mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (A), if $X$ isn't nowhere dense, namely $\mathrm{cl}(X)$ contains a nondegenerate interval, then so does $X'$ and every $X^{(n)}$, so $X$ is not of first species.

For (B), if finitely many closed intervals cover $X$ then they also cover $\mathrm{cl}(X)$, so $X$ has zero Jordan content iff $\mathrm{cl}(X)$ does. In particular, if $\mathrm{cl}(X)$ contains an interval, then $X$ cannot have zero Jordan content.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping confirm my suspicions!

Answer (score 2):

Yes to both questions:

For the first question, let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ be of first species. I claim that $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X)) \subset X^{(n)}$ for all $n \geq 1$. This can be proved by induction: When $n = 1$, let $X_{\mathrm{iso}}$ be the set of isolated points of $X$. Then $X^{(1)} = X' = \mathrm{cl}(X) \setminus X_{\mathrm{iso}}$. For any $x \in X_{\mathrm{iso}}$, clearly $x$ is isolated in $\mathrm{cl}(X)$ as well, so $x \notin \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X))$. Thus, $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X)) \subset \mathrm{cl}(X) \setminus X_{\mathrm{iso}} = X^{(1)}$.

Assume the result has been proved for some $n$. Consider $X^{(n+1)} = (X^{(n)})'$. By induction assumption, $O = \mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X)) \subset X^{(n)}$. $O$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, so all points in it are limit points of $O$, therefore also of $X^{(n)}$. Thus, $O \subset (X^{(n)})' = X^{(n+1)}$.

Of course, this implies that if $X^{(n)} = \varnothing$ for some $n$, then $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X)) = \varnothing$.

For the second question, it is not hard to see that in the definition we may assume $\mathcal{I} = \{I_1, \cdots, I_n\}$ is a finite collection of closed intervals. Thus, $\cup_j I_j$ is closed, so if $X \subset \cup_j I_j$, then so does $\mathrm{cl}(X) \subset \cup_j I_j$. As such, if $X$ is of zero Jordan content, then so does $\mathrm{cl}(X)$ and then also $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X))$. If $\mathrm{int}(\mathrm{cl}(X)) \neq \varnothing$, then it contains a nonempty open interval, whence the said nonempty open interval must be of zero Jordan content as well, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping confirm my suspicions!